# No default constructor for class member that is a template object itself

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, initialization, default

I'm trying to write a simple class for binary search tree that uses a class of nodes using templates. This is my code:

When I try to compile the code I get this error:
 `'Node<T>': no appropriate default constructor available'`
 
for this line: 
 
`Tree() : root(0), counter(0) {}`
 
 
and I don't understand why it would even use a default constructor here I'm just giving a value to a pointer of the class type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Node {
public:
    Node(const T &value) : value(value), Left(0), Right(0) {}

    ~Node() {
        if (Left != 0)
            delete Left;
        if (Right != 0)
            delete Right;
    }

    Node& getLeft() { return *Left; }

    Node& getRight() { return *Right; }

private:
    Node* Left;
    Node* Right;
    T value;
};


template <typename T>
class Tree : public Node<T> {
public:
    template<typename T>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Tree<T> &t);

    Tree() : root(0), counter(0) {}

    Tree(const T &rootValue) : root(new Node<T>(rootValue)), counter(1) {}

    ~Tree() { delete root; }

    Tree& insert(const T &value) {
        Node<T> *runner = root;
        Node<T> *replacer = root;
        if (runner == 0)
            root = new Node<T>(value);
        else
        {
            while (runner != 0)
            {
                replacer = runner;
                if (value > runner->value)
                    runner = runner->Right;
                else
                    runner = runner->Left;
            }
            if (value > replacer->value)
                replacer->Right = new Node<T>(value);
            else
                replacer->Left = new Node<T>(value);
        }
        counter++;
        return *this;
    }

    bool exists(const T &value) const {
        Node<T> *runner = root;
        while (runner != 0)
        {
            if (value == runner->value)
                return true;
            if (value > runner->value)
                runner = runner->Right;
            else
                runner = runner->Left;
        }
        return false;
    }

    int size() const { return size; }

private:
    Node<T> *root;
    int counter;
};

template<typename T>
string preorderToString(const Node<T> &n) {  //Function that receives a tree and returns a string of the preorder traversal of it
    string left, middle, right;
    if (n.Left != 0)
        left = preorderToString((*n.Left)) + " ";
    middle = to_string(n.value);
    if (n.Right != 0)
        right = " " + preorderToString((*n.Right));
    return  left + middle + right;
}

template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Tree<T> &t) //Operator overloading that uses the function 'preorderToString' to print the tree contents
{
    return output << preorderToString<T>(*(t.root));
}


int main() {
    Tree<double> test;
}
```

Comment: Note that your don't respect rule of 5/3/0, you should probably implement your smart pointer if you cannot use std ones.

Comment: You can use `nullptr` to represent null pointers after c++11, and this will help others to understand your code better.

Answer (score 0):

The message is a little misleading: it's not complaining about the members you've initialised, but the base that you *didn't* initialise. Therefore it's trying to use a default constructor of the base (`Node<double>`) that doesn't exist.

Perhaps you didn't mean to make `Tree<T>` derive from `Node<T>`?

Fixing that (and the shadowed `T` on that friend declaration), [the code compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ee5d17f77dcfbcd).